# Energy-momentum conservation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conservation-laws, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I used energy-momentum tensor for electromagnetism, and want to prove energy-momentum conservation using the equations of motion.
$$T_{EM} ^{μν}=F^{μλ} F_λ^ν-η^{μν} F^{ρσ} F_{ρσ}$$
$$∂_μ(T_{EM} ^{μν})=∂_μ(F^{μλ} F_λ^ν-η^{μν} F^{ρσ} F_{ρσ})=∂_μ(F^{μλ})F_λ^ν+F^{μλ}∂_μ(F_λ^ν)-2η^{μν} F^{ρσ}∂_μ(F_{ρσ})$$
$$, ∂_μ(F^{μλ})=0$$
but, how I can prove: 
$$η^{νρ}F^{μλ}∂_μ(F_{λρ})-2η^{μν} F^{ρσ}∂_μ(F_{ρσ})=0 ~?$$
to reach
$$ ∂_μ(T_{EM}^{μν})=0 $$

Comment: The energy-momentum tensor for the electromagnetic field is $T^{\mu\nu} = F^{\mu\lambda} F^{\nu}_{\lambda} - \frac{1}{4} \eta^{\mu\nu} F^{\rho\sigma} F_{\rho\sigma}$. So try again with this expression.

Comment: thanks, but 1/4 is just a coefficient. and didn't help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ T^{μν}_{EM}=F^μ_{λ}F^ν_{λ}−(1/4) η^{μν}F^{ρσ}F_{ρσ} $$
$$∂_μ(T_{EM} ^{μν})=∂_μ(F^{μλ})F_λ^ν+F^{μλ}∂_μ(F_λ^ν)-(1/4)η^{μν} ∂_μ(F^{ρσ}F_{ρσ})$$
$$ ∂_μ(F^{ρσ}F_{ρσ})=∂_μ(F^{ρσ})F_{ρσ}+F^{ρσ}∂_μ(F_{ρσ})=2F^{ρσ}∂_μ(F_{ρσ})=2F^{ρσ}(-∂_λ(F_{σμ})-∂_σ(F_{μλ}) $$
$$=>∂_μ(F_{ρσ})=-4F^{ρσ}∂_λ(F_{σμ}) $$
$$ =>∂_μ(T_{EM} ^{μν})=F^{μλ}∂_μ(F_λ^ν)-F^{λσ}∂_λ(F^ν_σ)=0 $$